# Webpack/Babel installation for ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I just started learning ReactJS and came across something called as webpack which is basically a module bundler.

Somehow,I'm stuck with the configuration of the same and the following error keeps coming.

**ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16**

**Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)**

**You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.**

> ```
> render()
> {
>     return (<div> <h1> Hi </h1> </div>);
> }
> ```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 2

npm ERR! reactsetup@1.0.0 start: `webpack --mode=development ./src/index.js -o bundle.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 2

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the reactsetup@1.0.0 start script.

Here is my **Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "reactsetup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development ./src/index.js -o bundle.js",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp index.html dist/index.html &&  webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "dev-start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import {render} from "react-dom"      

class App extends React.Component {
    render()
    {
        return (<div> <h1> Hi </h1> </div>);

    }

}

render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**web.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ {
            test: /\.js?/,

            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
                }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
};

    module.exports = config
```

And lastly, **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: This is my first question ever on stackoverflow. Apologies for the flaws,if any.

Comment: That's jsx file not a js file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are a couple of things

1. rename `web.config.js` to `webpack.config.js`
2. install `babel-preset-react`
3. change your HTML to the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var config = {
  entry: SRC_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,

        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

One tip, use [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to start fast with react :)

Comment: Changing the file name did work. But there's some configuration error now.
"Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema".  But thankyou anyway. And I'll definitely use "create-react-app". Again,thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @ShivamSingh I updated my answer, now you can see my webpack.config.js

Comment: @ShivamSingh you are welcome, when my answer is correct, please mark it :)

Comment: I tried doing it, but apparently if your reputation is less than 15,you can't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

the default name for config is "webpack.config.js", not the "web.config.js". And you don't pass the "--config" property either. So it looks like your webpack config is not used at all.

I believe, renaming config to the "webpack.config.js" could help you

Comment: It did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for a beginner to set-up the React environment is to use `create-react-app`.

I'm assuming that you already have node installed. If not a quick Google search will instruct you how to install nodejs.

After that run the following command in the directory where you want to create the project

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

Then open your browser and go to `localhost:3000` and you should see your react template.

More information on create-react-app can be found via the following links

[github page](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

[react official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html)

Comment: I'll definitely go ahead with this. Thanks :)

Comment: be aware tho that create-react-app actually hides configuration, namely webpack.config file so you dont have to deal with it. if you want to to learn using webpack as well try finding some forks of create-react-app which have webpack exposed.

Comment: there is an option in create-react-app where you can run `npm run eject` to unpack everything and it will give you all config files for babel and webpack. After you eject you won't be able to go back though!